# GoLang Decrypt a command than execute it

Tags: encryption, go, aes

So I was wondering if you can decrypt a command than execute it...

So the command is a exec.Command and I want to encrypt it in a separate file. Than take the hash (AES) and decrypt it in another file separately than when it is decrypted I want to execute it.

I'm fairly new to Golang so excuse my misunderstanding of the language and its capabilities.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I guess that you mean 'then' instead of 'than'.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the encryption/decryption, you can look at [`crypto/cipher/example_test.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/example_test.go).

All you need to is to [write the encrypted result into a file](https://gobyexample.com/writing-files), or [read the encrypted result](https://gobyexample.com/reading-files).

Once decrypted, you can execute the string (provided it is a valid command) with exec.Command: see [`os/exec/example_test.go`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/example_test.go).